# Functionality in highcharts which support a spline chart and inverted stacked column in a same chart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Do we have functionality in highcharts which support a spline chart and inverted stacked column in a same chart like the below chart? If yes, Can you please provide some code samples? I have given a mock image below.

Note : In the below image please consider the spline chart and the bottom activity stacked bar chart alone

Mock Graph Image:

[image: Mock Graph Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spline` and `xrange` series types with multiple `yAxis`:

```
series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    data: [...]
}, {
    type: 'xrange',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [...]
}],
yAxis: [{
    height: '50%',
    offset: 0
}, {
    height: '50%',
    top: '50%',
    offset: 0
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/srjncbL3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis